# SignalR performance counters on Windows Server 2012 R2 not reporting data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, performancecounter, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I'm running an ASP.NET MVC page with SignalR on IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

I've installed the SignalR performance counters using the tool signalr.exe (from the `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Utils` package)

I have added the application pool to `Performance Monitor Users` group according to [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/idof/2013/08/20/fixing-iis-advanced-logging-performance-counters-errors/)

As I open `perfmon` and add the SignalR performance counters, there is no data reported, they all show 0 all the time.

What am I missing? What can I do to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

Make the app pool identity to LocalSystem (Applications Pools -> Advanced Settings -> Identity). You do not need to add application pool to "performance monitor users group" to try this solution.